# how to get tabhost in activity which implemented TabListener interface

Tags: android, android-animation, android-tabhost

I am trying to add animation in tabs while navigating into tabs.

I am done with implmentation of tab bar appearance by implementing ActionBar.TabListener interface.

I googled and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009155/android-tabactivity-with-transition-animation) for adding animation. but it is demanding tabhost to get the animation in to screen.

so question is, is tabhost available if we implement tabbar appearance by extending TabListener interface. bcoz I am asking after searching for how to get tabhost and no luck.

if so how to get gettabhost in the above approach and add animation plz.

I implemented the tablistener and mycode in corresponding methods.

```
public class TabbarActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener
```