# tabhost transaction fragment effects

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost, effects

it is possibile give effects to sliding in a `tabHost` ?
my tabHos is inside this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_shadow">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </TabWidget>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and i setup my tabHost in a `fragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_marks, container, false);

    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment1);
   //

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            FragmentTest.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            FragmentTest2.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            FragmentTest.class, null);

    //mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new AnimatedTabHostListener(mTabHost));
    return mTabHost;
}
```

I'm not sure if also in this case is also possibile give a slide effects to the views.
I mean when you click a tab u will see an effects in the transaction of the fragment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10010236/4232337

Comment: i saw this post, the listeners are called but id dont see any animations when i tap the tabs

Comment: Did you try to replace `getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener())` with `mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener())` ?

Comment: @NSimon yes i did and it doesnt work (i debugged and the listeners are called but i dont see any animations. maybe because i'm using a fragment with tabHost instead of an activity?

Comment: How about trying to launch it? `Animation animation = inFromRightAnimation();
        currentView.startAnimation(animation);`

Comment: i tried 2 way: way1 - set the animation to the current view and after start it by the method startAnimation, way 2 - directly start. doesnt work... i dont see any animation... maybe is the currentView that i get wrong ?