# TabHost Animation with changed tab

Tags: java, android, listview, animation

I trying to add an animation to when the tabs change, I have a list view as my tabs, and right now I have got animation working. Using this

```
    getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
     public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
     {
            View currentView = getTabHost().getCurrentView();
            if (getTabHost().getCurrentTab() > currentTab)
            {
                currentView.setAnimation( inFromRightAnimation() );
            }
            else
            {
                currentView.setAnimation( outToRightAnimation() );
            }

            currentTab = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
     }
});
```

And this

```
public Animation inFromRightAnimation()
{
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    inFromRight.setDuration(240);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromRight;
}

public Animation outToRightAnimation()
{
    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    outtoLeft.setDuration(240);
    outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoLeft;
}
```

Based on the following post:

[Android - TabActivity with Transition animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009155/android-tabactivity-with-transition-animation)

But with my list view, I have a header on it, and I want the header to stay and just have the list change, how could I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `findViewById()` method of `getTabHost().getCurrentView()` chain, to find your `ListView` and animate it.

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        View currentView = getTabHost().getCurrentView();
        ListView listView = (ListView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.your_list_id);
        if (getTabHost().getCurrentTab() > currentTab)
        {
            listView.setAnimation( inFromRightAnimation() );
        }
        else
        {
            listView.setAnimation( outToRightAnimation() );
        }

        currentTab = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
 }
});
```